# Localization problems in iPhone/iPad app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, localization

I have localized an App for English and Lithuanian. Preferred language is English. Problem is that users which are located in Lithuania can not see Lithuanian version because in the **Settings -> General -> International -> Language** no way to set language to Lithuanian.

What is the best way to make that user in Lithuania will be able to see Lithuanian version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might add some way for user to chose language once user is on the app, it is kind of way we usually use in the websites. This could be alternative for showing the app in the language not supported in the `AppleLanguage` keys. You might want to use this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259695/translating-ios-app-to-unsupported-non-standard-languages) to solve your problem. It is also good idea to send some kind of request to apple for adding the Lithuanian language which is not currently available for supported languages in iOS.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I do not like this solution, but it looks like only one way to go for now. As well I reported the problem in Apple bug report system: Bug ID# 13756331.