# iOS localization for unsupported languages

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, internationalization

I want to offer a “Nynorsk localization” option  for my app. In the device settings there is no such option, but it looks like iOS actually supports this language, since  `availableLocaleIdentifiers` do contain `nn`:

```
kCFLocaleCountryCodeKey = NO;
kCFLocaleLanguageCodeKey = nn;
```

So I'm confused, is Norwegian Nynorsk supported or not? It's not among device's international languages, but it is among `availableLocaleIdentifiers`.

I know there are [some ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259695/translating-ios-app-to-unsupported-non-standard-languages) to make  custom ‘localizable strings’ work, but so far I did not find a way to make iOS return proper strings for instance for system buttons  (Delete button for `UITableViewCell`, `UIBarButtonItem`-s from `initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action`, etc).
So the question is if there is a way to indicate a locale for system controls.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22805892/1488608 this *might* be your answer

Answer (score 2):

[Translating iOS app to unsupported/non-standard languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259695/translating-ios-app-to-unsupported-non-standard-languages)

[Choosing localization for unsupported languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663954/ios-choosing-localization-for-unsupported-language)

http://applingua.com/supporting-unsupported-languages-in-ios/